# Linking an SVG polygon to an anchor

Tags: html, css, svg, anchor, href

I'm trying to do something seemingly relatively simple, but after much googling and finicking , I can't seem to make it work.
I have an svg polygon that I'm using to clip an image into a triangle.
Currently it's inside a bootstrap column, (with an a tag in it) that links to an anchor point. 
The issue with this, is that the div(square) all links to the anchor.

However, I have a bunch of these triangles adjoining, so I need the area that links to the anchor to be restricted to only what's inside the polygon clip path.

I have tried:

- Moving the a tag inside the clippath tag
- moving the a tag inside the polygon (as an href)
- making the href in this format for svg xlink:href="#portfolioModal3"

I suspect it's some permutation of the third option that accomplishes my goal.

```
<div class="col-sm-4 portfolio-item dontwantpadding">
                    <a href="#portfolioModal3" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
                        <div class='tri-up'>
                            <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 87">
                              <clipPath id="clipTriangleUp">
                                <polygon points="0 87,100 87,50 0"/>
                              </clipPath>
                              <image clip-path="url(#clipTriangleUp)" preserveAspectRatio="none" width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href="http://placehold.it/1749x1510"/>
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
```

I plan on making the svg paths transition to circles from triangles, so something that will adapt to a circle svg path is ideal.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SVGs can have `<a>` elements.  Try putting your link inside your SVG.

```
<div class="col-sm-4 portfolio-item dontwantpadding">
   <div class='tri-up'>
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 87">
         <clipPath id="clipTriangleUp">
            <polygon points="0 87,100 87,50 0"/>
         </clipPath>
         <a id="svgtriangle"
            xlink:href="#portfolioModal3" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
            <image clip-path="url(#clipTriangleUp)" preserveAspectRatio="none"
                   width="100%" height="100%"
                   xlink:href="http://placehold.it/1749x1510"/>
         </a>
      </svg>
   </div>
</div>
```

Hopefully you won't have any issue with Bootstrap finding the `data-toggle`.

**Update**

Okay, so it seems Bootstrap won't find your modal "open" link automatically, so you need to add a click handler to the triangle and open the modal yourself.

```
var  triangle = document.getElementById("svgtriangle");

triangle.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

[Demo fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/7bwm0scu/)

Comment: I think you'll need xlink:href on the <a> element for it to be handled as an anchor.

Comment: Thanks Erik. Forgot to change that.

Comment: ooo so close! @PaulLeBeau thanks for responding. Now the cursor changes on the triangle mouse-over, but still doesn't open up the anchor on click. Any thoughts? Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Are you relying on Bootstrap finding the modal link automatically?  Have you tried explicitly adding the modal using `$('#portfolioModal3').modal(options)`?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I guess I am? I'm not sure what you mean by "explicitly adding" though that could very well be the issue. The model doesn't exist on the page and is a "pop up" of sorts. Where would I add that code? it looks like js

Comment: @PaulLeBeau just to better clarify the problem as I try things: If I remove the "xlink:" before the href in your code, then the area outside of the triangle is no longer selectable and the inside is, but a part of the problem remains because: the cursor doesn't change to a hand indicating that clicking is possible, and half of the triangle is non-clickable because it adjoins another triangle pointing opposite (down) and half of it is covered by the square div of the second triangle (even though the second triangle also has the href moved as your code shows). Does that make sense?

Comment: The "xlink:" prefix is required for `<a>` links in SVG.  You can't remove it.  And yes, the snippet I posted is JS.  It may be that Bootstrap can't automatically find the `data-toggle` attribute when it is in an SVG.  That javascript will explicitly add it.  At least in HTML anyway - I haven't tried it in an SVG context myself.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau yea, still no success. I'm shocked that it's this difficult to make linkable triangles :/ I really appreciate all of your help though. Where I currently  am with your fix is: it make it so the selection cursor disappears outside of the triangle, but also disappears on the right side of the triangle (assuringly because it is covered by the adjoining div). And, it is not selectable.

Comment: Paul, I did a bunch of research, and apparently SVGs have no z-index and their essential z-index is determined by their order. Do you think this means I'll always have one svg overlapped by another since the divs have negative margins pushing them together? I need to somehow figure out how to get just the triangles on top, and not the entire rectangular SVG.

Comment: Okay so it seems (as I suspected) that you need to open the modal yourself.  I've updated my answer.  As for your overlapping `<div>`s that's a problem.  AFAIK there is no easy cross-browser way to do that.  You are going to have to put all the triangles in the same SVG.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I don't know how I missed your response, sorry! I did come to that conclusion about all triangles in the same SVG and have come thus far(got them all in same svg, just have messed up backgrounds), any finishing help you have would be great:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28443229/using-d3-to-fill-an-svg-with-a-background-image

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the a tag inside and directly surrounding the image only.

```
<a><img src="foo" /></a>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding Eric! That does give me the click-cursor only on mouse-over of the triangle (what I want). But, when I actually click nothing happens.